# How does 'quiver' function work in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How does the quiver function work? I know it creates vector arrows but what do u,v,x and y variables actually mean?

- Is there a relation between u-x and v-y?
- How is the actual length of the arrow determined and how does it affect the 4 variables above?
- Does u,v mean 'from' and x,y mean 'to' which will create the arrow head at x,y with start location at u,v?

Comment: In terms of image processing, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340192/1586200) for usage.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, Thanks but I am looking for description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x`, `y` are the horizontal and vertical **coordinates of the origin** of each vector.

`u`, `v` are the horizontal and vertical **components** of each vector. Thus the length of the vectors would be `sqrt(u.^2 + v.^2)`. But there's a **normalization** in `u`, `v` so that maximum length is a nice value that avoids one vector overlapping (or getting into the "area" of) another vector.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, and with some advice i managed to overlap contours and quiver 
I have posted the code in the answers ([Contouring a mesh and assigning magnitude arrows in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825299/contouring-a-mesh-and-assigning-magnitude-arrows-in-matlab/25385507#25385507))

take a look it may be of help to you as well

```
[nx,ny]= size(A) % A is the matrix used as base
xx=1:1:ny; % set the x-axis to be equal to the y
yy=1:1:nx; % set the y-axis to be equal to the x
contourf(xx,yy,A)
hold on, delta = 8; %delta is the distance between arrows)
quiver(xx(1:delta:end),yy(1:delta:end),B(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),C(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),1) % the 1 at the end is the size of the arrows
set(gca,'fontsize',12);, hold off
```